# Как для анимированного элемента однократно отключить анимацию для мгновенного изменения стиля?

Tags: javascript, css3, анимация, transition

Т.е. есть изменения которые должны происходить с анимацией, а есть те, что меняют те же параметры, но должны происходить мгновенно. Попытался сделать так, но не работает:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div'),
    width = 10;

function inc() {
    width += 10;
    if (width > 100) width = 10;
    div.style.width = width + '%';
}

document.getElementById('ba').addEventListener('click', inc);

document.getElementById('bna').addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.classList.add('no-animation');
    inc();
    div.classList.remove('no-animation');
});
```

```css
.animated-div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #448;
    
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
         -o-transition: width 0.5s;
            transition: width 0.5s;
}

.no-animation {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
       -moz-transition: none !important;
         -o-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="ba" value="Animation"/><input type="button" id="bna" value="No animation"/>
<div class="animated-div" id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое поведение на мой взгляд очень неочевидно. Дело все в том, что все правила CSS в какой-то момент кэшируются и ваше изменение(добавление CSS правил из класса `no-animation`) не успевает вступить в силу. Такое поведение понятно и в большинстве случаев оно никак не мешает.

В данном случае необходимо принудительно *перекомпоновать* (обновить кеш) CSS перед удалением класса `no-animation`. Сделать это можно [многими способами](http://gent.ilcore.com/2011/03/how-not-to-trigger-layout-in-webkit.html), но чаще всего достаточно просто обратиться к полю `offsetHeight` элемента.

Обращение к этому полю заставляет кеш CSS обновится и применить новые правила к элементам DOM.

**Отредактированная версия кода (*Добавлена одна строка*):**

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div'),
    width = 10;

function inc() {
    width += 10;
    if (width > 100) width = 10;
    div.style.width = width + '%';
}

document.getElementById('ba').addEventListener('click', inc);

document.getElementById('bna').addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.classList.add('no-animation');
    inc();
    div.offsetHeight; // Вот эта строка творит 'магию'!
    div.classList.remove('no-animation');
});
```

```css
.animated-div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #448;
    
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
         -o-transition: width 0.5s;
            transition: width 0.5s;
}

.no-animation {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
       -moz-transition: none !important;
         -o-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="ba" value="Animation"/><input type="button" id="bna" value="No animation"/>
<div class="animated-div" id="div"></div>
```

Comment: Да, точно! Вспомнил, что уже сталкивался с подобным. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что это происходит потому, что вы уже задали для дива переходы, и они, видимо, уже не перетираются. Или до функции анимации доходит очередь так быстро, что `add('no-animation')` не успевает просто сработать

Могу предложить сделать отдельные классы для анимации и для "неанимации".

```js
var div = document.getElementById('div'),
    width = 10;

function inc() {
    width += 10;
    if (width > 100) width = 10;
    div.style.width = width + '%';
}

document.getElementById('ba').addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.classList.remove('no-animation');    
    div.classList.add('animation');
    inc();    
});

document.getElementById('bna').addEventListener('click', function() {
    div.classList.remove('animation');
    div.classList.add('no-animation');        
    inc();
});
```

```css
.animated-div {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    background: #448;
    
}

.animation {
    -webkit-transition: width 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: width 0.5s;
         -o-transition: width 0.5s;
            transition: width 0.5s;    

}

.no-animation {
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
       -moz-transition: none !important;
         -o-transition: none !important;
            transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="ba" value="Animation"/><input type="button" id="bna" value="No animation"/>
<div class="animated-div" id="div"></div>
```